# Как в android studio подключить библиотеку?

Tags: android-studio

У меня есть проект, который нужно сделать библиотекой другого проекта. В Eclipse это было достаточно легко сделать. Как это сделать в Android Studio?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 4):

в Android Studio это еще легче сделать

GUI путь:
File -> Project Sturture -> жмешь плюсик СЛЕВА и добавляешь свой проект , который хочешь использовать , как библиотеку , через список ниже больших квадратов : Import Existing Project - она там посинхронизируется какое то время , затем раздел Modules:<Имя модуля в который добавляется библиотека> -> вкладка Dependencies , жмешь плюсик СПРАВА и добавляешь библиотеку в зависимости от типа ( внешняя (maven) , локальная (.jar ) или модуль . В вашем случае ,по всей видимости ,подходит третий вариант  ( модуль , который вы только что добавили ) . 
Если нужно подключить готовую библиотеку .jar или из maven , то первую часть (добавление модуля в проект ) делать не требуется , просто добавляешь нужную библиотеку на вкладке Dependencies

Hand путь :
прописываешь библиотеки вручную в файле конфигурации модуля build.gradle в разделе dependencies {}

[как прописать разные типы библиотек](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#buildFileBasics) , раздел: Declare dependencies